# Confusion on Fedora RPM build

Tags: fedora, rpmbuild

I'm trying to rebuild Fedora with some changes in the .config file of the kernel configurations. I'm trying to follow the steps in this guide: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Building_a_custom_kernel/Source_RPM

However, all throughout the wiki, it's referencing a directory labeled ~/rpmbuild/BUILD, but it never actually shows when to create it, how to set it up, or which files are in it.

Can someone fill in the knowledge gap?

Answer (score 4):

Those instructions are pretty sorely lacking.  That directory won’t exist until you run one of the `rpmbuild -bb …` commands later in the instructions, because that’s the source that’s extracted from SOURCES and all the patches.

Probably whoever wrote it had the files already there from previous builds, and didn’t realize it’s empty on your first run.

I suggest just running a regular rpmbuild on the default kernel spec to see what it looks like, then you can add your own patches later.p, and the BUILD will exist.